# Get cross-company data in Azure data factory using ODATA

Tags: odata, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure data factory - copy activity to export data to the data lake. I am using Dynamics 365 F&Ô- ODATA and I have data in multiple companies. I would like to get data from all companies for one of the entities and export it to the data lake.  When I preview my dataset with a table then I can see data only for one company. I try to add the parameter "cross-company = true" but still it is showing one company data.

How can I solve this problem?

Regards,
Parag Chapre

Answer (score 0):

Preview option in dataset only gives you few rows of data for sampling purpose only. We cannot rely on preview option to see our entier data. Kindly execute your pipeline and validate your results.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After executing my pipeline, I cannot see data from all companies.